# The Next Statement Doesn't Get Executed - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show users **Page Loading** feature when there's a delay in data load. It works but in reverse way.Say there is a table in a page and if the table length is zero, then it'll show a **Page Loading** feature like **Please Wait**. So I've tried something like this with `jQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.29.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function () {
                if ($('table').length != 0) { //Checking the table length here
                    swal.close(); //Close when data uploaded
                    console.log($('table').length);
                }
                else if ($('table').length == 0) {
                    swal.showLoading(); //Show when data upload delayed or zero
                    console.log($('table').length);
                }
            });
</script>
```

This is simple but it doesn't show the **Please Wait** feature when it uploads data initially in the page. When I try the reverse, say, page loaded and then the feature works perfectly. Anything I missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the load event of Jquery will trigger after all the elements inside the window are loaded completely.  That's why your code will only work when the the loading is already finish (when you reverse it).

```
$(window).load(function () {
```

everything inside this function will trigger after the page completely loaded. Try to do this.

```
if ($('table').length == 0) {
    swal.showLoading(); //Show when data upload delayed or zero
    console.log($('table').length);
}

$(window).load(function () {
      if ($('table').length != 0) { //Checking the table length here
          swal.close(); //Close when data uploaded
          console.log($('table').length);
      }
});
```

reference: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Tried that @Ryan RR. Any other way to do it? I kept the first condition out of the window load but didn't work.

Comment: probably remove the if statement of the first condition
    
    if ($('table').length == 0) {